# mysql SHOW tablename performance guard

Tags: mysql, mariadb

An application creates a mysql table `FOO_{id}` for every foo that is created.  In the application we access data for a FOO with a certain id with a query

```
SELECT * FROM FOO_{id}
```

A valid use case is an attempt to access a foo with an id that doesn't exist.  Currently we don't check if the table exists before firing the query, we simply process the `Table FOO_{id} doesn't exist` error.  What will the performance gain be if we guard the query with a show tables query?

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'FOO_{id}'
```

Comment: performance gain? really you get a performance loss off couple milliseconds because `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'FOO_{id}' ` triggers a random disk I/o to find the table file.

Comment: One table per ID? This looks like a very bad design..